# $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x}{x^3+1}dx$ is convergent or divergent?

Tags: integration

Use the Comparison Theorem to determine whether the integral is convergent or divergent.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x}{x^3+1}dx$$
[Comparison Theorem:Suppose that $f$ and  $g$ are continuous functions with $f(x)\ge g(0)\ge0$ , for$x\ge a$. If $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ is convergent, then $\int_{a}^{\infty} g(x)dx$ is convergent.]

My method:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x}{x^3+1}dx$$
Since $x\lt{x^3+1}$ for $x\in [0,{\infty})$, $\frac {x}{x^3+1}\lt 0$ for $x\in[0,{\infty})$.
$\int_{0}^{\infty} 0dx =0\Rightarrow$ converges to $0$.
Therefore, by Comparison Theorem, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x}{x^3+1}dx$$ also convergents.

I'm not sure that whether my method is correct.
Is there any wrong??

Comment: $\frac x{x^3+1}\geq0$ for $x\in [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statment

> Since $x <x^3+1$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$, $\frac{x}{x^3+1}<0$

is not quite right. For instance, with $x=1$, it's true $x =1 < x^3+1 = 2$. But $\frac{x}{x^3+1} = \frac{1}{2} > 0$

Instead, I would break your integral up into $(0,1)$, and $(1, \infty)$, for instance. Show convergence over $(0,1)$ by comparison with $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1} \ \text{d}x = \ln(2)$$ and over $(1,\infty)$ by comparison with $$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} \ \text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Both of which work out, as can be seen graphically

[image]

**In Response to Your Comment**

Well, you could view it in two ways. On the one hand, you could simply say that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x = \int_0^1 \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x  =\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1}$$ Then simply note that $a<b$ and $c<d$ gives $a+c < b+d$ to say that the total integral is at most $\ln(2) + \frac{\pi}{4}$, which, it's clear, is finite. In this case, effectively what we're doing is saying $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x < \ln (2) + \int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x $$ and in turn this new integral is convergent. That is, the sum of a finite number (2) of convergent integrals is convergent. But, if you want to  view it as effectively defining a function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x+1} & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ \frac{1}{x^2+1} & x>1\end{cases} $$ then $f$ *is* a continuous function with $f(x) \geq \frac{x}{x^3+1}  \geq 0$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. (In particular, this function is the green above on $[0,1]$ and the red above on $(1, \infty)$, and you can readily see it is continuous and has no vertical asymptotes). What is true is that this function $f$ is not continuously differentiable (it's not differentiable at $x=1$, but it *is* continuous, and thus it is integrable, and so the comparison test with $f$ over $[0, \infty)$ suffices to show convergence.

But, I should state, that we don't *have* to split up the function into parts if you don't want to do that, there are plenty of other ways to tackle the problem. For instance, one could integrate directly with

$$\int \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x = \int \left( \frac{x+1}{3(x^2-x+1)} - \frac{1}{3(x+1)} \right) \ \text{d}x $$ so that in turn it's not hard to see  $$ \int \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x = \frac{1}{6} \ln (x^2 - x+1) - \frac{1}{3}\ln(x+1) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan \left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) $$ and from here it's more or less a trivial exercise in limits to show precisely that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b \frac{x}{x^3+1} \ \text{d}x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{6} \ln (x^2 - x+1) - \frac{1}{3}\ln(x+1) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan \left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \right) - \lim_{x \to 0}\left( \frac{1}{6} \ln (x^2 - x+1) - \frac{1}{3}\ln(x+1) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \arctan \left( \frac{2x-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right) = \frac{2\pi}{3 \sqrt{3}} $$ So, there are lots of other ways to show convergence if you don't want to split the integral up, but splitting the function up, for instance, as above works out very conveniently.

Comment: May I ask a question? We do know that the function is continuous (does not have any vertical asymptotes ). Why we need to split the integral into two parts??

Comment: My response was too long to comment, so I've edited the answer to include an explanation that I hope helps

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out $a<b$ does not imply $\frac a b<0$. Split the integral into two parts, $\int_0^{1} \frac x {1+x^{3}} dx <\infty$ (any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is integrable) and $\int_1^{\infty} \frac x {1+x^{3}} dx \leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac x {x^{3}} dx=1$.